# Using page.tpl.php in a module

Tags: 7

I want to override and use page.tpl.php from within my module. I think I can do this with hook_theme_registry_alter(). So I don't want Bartik to override this, however, I want a sub theme of Bartik to be able to override it and use its own implementation of page.tpl.php, if it exists.

How would I do this? Do I put a condition in hook_theme_registry_alter(), if so, how can I tell if the current theme is a sub theme of Bartik?